# article usage. to order a cake on a plate

Tags: articles

What article should I use in this phrase

They oreder(ed) a cake on a plate, and stay(ed) to the end

What are the possible variations in meaning and form?

Comment: You probably want to ask questions like this on [ELL.SE].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nouns that can be both count and noncount nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469071/nouns-that-can-be-both-count-and-noncount-nouns) The count and non-count usages of _cake_ are addressed.

Comment: I have posted here, to get ideas from "language thinkers" not "standard issue link posters"

Comment: Well that does take the cake.

Comment: I would have thought that most cakes come on plates. Why would someone specifically order "(a) cake on a plate"? That said, was it one cake, to be sliced by the customers, or individual slices served on a single plate or each with its own plate? The order itself just seems unusual to me. Of course, you could order a piece of cake wrapped in plastic, but in that event, you'd probably say, "I ordered a piece of cake". In order to answer your question or know if a previous question applies here.

Comment: It is very unusual to specify the plate when ordering.

Comment: It is indeed unusual to specify such things. This is why I'm asking. So, suppose a cake on a plate is a children's rhyme, or a piece of poetry. I'm wondering, how to make it grammatically correct at least, still better, more natural sounding.